# Page product. For a attribute size select box vs small rectangle

Tags: attributes, product-page

In page product, for select the size, i want to use not a select box but a small rectangle.

My web site(for size use a select box):
http://vispateresa-shop.com/it/prodotto-1

The exemple (use a rectangle box):
http://ultimo.infortis-themes.com/demo/second2/top9.html

how make this? I thick it's a simple setting from backend.

Thanks.
Ale

Comment: If you are using CE1.9 then this comes out of the box. You just need to look for the config that enables it in system->configuration.

Comment: You know where is this configuration?

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend you [this free extension](https://github.com/tzyganu/Switcher). It allows you among other things to change any dropdown for configurable products to labels and/or images.
 [full documentation](https://github.com/tzyganu/Switcher/wiki) how it should be configured